# How to check which node has a GPU

Tags: cluster-computing, zsh, slurm, hpc

I want to run a batch job with two nodes. One node has a GPU and the other one does not. I can get the list of all nodes assigned by:

```
nodes=$(scontrol show hostnames "$SLURM_JOB_NODELIST")
```

How can U check in the batch script which node is the one with the GPU or which is the one without GPU?

Answer (score 0):

If you run a command such as `scontrol show -d job $SLURM_JOB_ID`, the output will contain lines such as

```
Nodes=nodexxx CPU_IDs=2-5,24-31 Mem=98304 GRES=gpu:1(IDX:2)
Nodes=nodeyyy CPU_IDs=8,14,27 Mem=12000 GRES=
```

which is probably the information you are looking for.

So you can try something like:

```
GPUNODE=$(scontrol show -d job $SLURM_JOB_ID | awk  '/Nodes=.*GRES=gpu/ {print $1}' | cut -d= -f2)
```

(the parsing `awk ... | cut` could certainly be improved but it seems to work)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it but i get a different output. The command scontrol show -d job $SLURM_JOB_ID didn't display the kind of list on the cluster i am working with. I solved the problem by using a heterogenous job with the first job beeing the GPU and the second one beeing the CPUs. (https://slurm.schedmd.com/heterogeneous_jobs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```
 scontrol show nodes | grep -e CfgTRES -e  AllocTRES -e NodeName -e Gres
```

It will print the gpus of each node.
AllocTRES means the current allocated resources.